# Revoke Create Type from an Oracle Schema

Tags: oracle

I am trying to stop people creating types in a schema.

```
colin @ colindev >create or replace type colin_obj as object(
  2    id varchar2(20)
  3  );
  4  /

Type created.
```

How do I stop this?

I have tried

```
SYS @ colindev >revoke create any type from colin;
revoke create any type from colin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01952: system privileges not granted to 'colin'
```

and the same thing in system instead of sys.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`revoke` only works if the privilege has already been `grant`ed. What's likely here is that `colin` has the privilege through a role that has been assigned to the user.

You don't really want to remove that privilege from the role as it will affect any user with that role; instead you'll need to give these users a different role that doesn't have `create any type` if you don't want them to do this (easiest way to do this is through the Enterprise Manager).

Comment: Just to add there are separate privileges CREATE TYPE and CREATE ANY TYPE. A user with CREATE TYPE can create types in their own schema, while the CREATE ANY TYPE is more powerful and means you can create a type in someone else's schema. Only DBAs might need the latter.